# Error with collections.sort (Bound mismatch)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, interface, comparable

I have to make an especific sort in a object. I read a lot of tutorials and utilized the class Comparable.

My Class:

```
public class PaAcao implements Serializable, IAcao, Comparable<PaAcao> /* Ordenar */  {

@Override
public int compareTo(PaAcao acaoCompara) {
    //return this.aresta - outro.aresta;
    int i = 0;
    String[] array1 = this.cnrAcao.split(".");
    String[] array2 = acaoCompara.cnrAcao.split(".");
    
    for(String c : array1){
        if (array2.length > i){             
            if (Integer.parseInt(c) > Integer.parseInt(array2[i])) 
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(c) < Integer.parseInt(array2[i])) 
            {
                return -1;
            }               
        }
        i++;
    }               
    return -1;
}
```

For this Class i have an interface:

```
package br.com.agraria.qualidade.model.entity;

public interface IAcao{

    public abstract String getCnmUsuarResp();   
    public abstract Usuario getusuarResp();
    public abstract void setusuarResp(Usuario usuarResp);
    public abstract PaStatusAcao getIcdStatus();
    public abstract String getCnrAcao();
    public abstract Boolean getLpublico();

}
```

And i get the error below:

```
public class PaAcaoServiceImpl extends HibernateGenericServiceImpl<PaAcao> implements PaAcaoService {
    @Override
    public List<? extends IAcao> processarAcoes(List<? extends IAcao> acoesProcessar) {
        SessaoPrivilegiosGerente sessaoPrivilegiosGerente = sessaoService.getSessaoPrivilegiosGerente();
        List<IAcao> macroRemover = new ArrayList<IAcao>();
    
        Collections.sort(acoesProcessar);
        
        ...

    }
}
```

The problem is in the line *Collections.sort(acoesProcessar);*
I get the message:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method `sort(List<T>)` of type Collections
> is not applicable for the arguments (`List<capture#14-of ? extends IAcao>`). The inferred type `capture#14-of ? extends IAcao` is not a
> valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Comment: I'm not 100%, but wouldn't the `IAcao` interface need to implement `Comparable`, if the list is going to use that type? If the list was of type `PaAcao` then I think it would be OK.

Comment: When do you return 0 for equal?  You must have `a.compareTo(b) = -b.compareTo(a)` so you cannot return anything but 0 for equal values.

Comment: Hi Peter, they never will be equal, the chance is 0.

Comment: Hi @Deactivator2, i already try that but i get an error in the PaAcao class, because i cannot implements 2 comparables in the same class.

Comment: @FryKlaus Right, that is because you can only have one class in your inheritance chain implement `Comparable`. In other words, if you declare `IAcao` to implement `Comparable`, you can't have `PaAcao` implement it as well, but the `compareTo` method will still work as an inherited method.

Comment: @Deactivator2 i try to extend the interface with Comparable and get it off of the PaPlano Class. I don't get any error, but if i run the code i get the following message: br.com.agraria.qualidade.model.entity.PaPlano cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: @FryKlaus try `public interface IAcao extends Comparable<IAcao>` and remove the `Comparable` implementation from the `PaAcao` class declaration.

Comment: @Deactivator2 i already did that but didn't work

Comment: @FryKlaus Did you do `extends` not `implements`? And please edit your question with all of your code updated.

Comment: @Deactivator2 Tnxs Man, your tips really helped, it's working now. The sort is wrong but this is another question that i'll have to work now! Tnxs man!

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was (Thanks [Deactivator2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211248/error-with-collections-sort/18232065#comment26693836_18211248) for helping me with this):

Extends Comparable on the interface IAcao:

```
package br.com.agraria.qualidade.model.entity;

public interface IAcao extends Comparable<IAcao>{

    public abstract String getCnmUsuarResp();   
    public abstract Usuario getusuarResp();
    public abstract void setusuarResp(Usuario usuarResp);
    public abstract PaStatusAcao getIcdStatus();
    public abstract String getCnrAcao();
    public abstract Boolean getLpublico();

}
```

And in my class PaAcao, I remove the implements of Comparable because it'll be duplicated and change the type os compareTo to IAcao and not PaAcao:

```
public class PaAcao implements Serializable, IAcao /* Ordenar */  {

@Override
public int compareTo(IAcao acaoCompara) {
    //return this.aresta - outro.aresta;
    int i = 0;
    String[] array1 = this.cnrAcao.split(".");
    String[] array2 = acaoCompara.cnrAcao.split(".");

    for(String c : array1){
        if (array2.length > i){             
            if (Integer.parseInt(c) > Integer.parseInt(array2[i])) 
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(c) < Integer.parseInt(array2[i])) 
            {
                return -1;
            }               
        }
        i++;
    }               
    return -1;
}
```